# How to revert css properties in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my jQuery function, I am animating a div element, so it moves 200px to right, receives a Moved class and some opacity:

```
if (!$(".block2").hasClass("Moved2")) {
    $(".block2").animate({
        "left": "+220px"
    }, "slow", function() {
        $.ajax
        ({url: 'play.php',
            data: {"var1": val},
            type: 'get',
            success: function(json) {
                if(!json.error) {$(".block2").removeClass("Moved2").css({left:"0",opacity:"1"});}
        }});
    } ).fadeTo("slow", 0.33).addClass("Moved2");
}
```

This works fine, but after it finishes, I want to have all properties and css back as they were before animation. But I don't want to reload the page.

As you can see, now I do it this way:

```
$(".block2").removeClass("Moved2").css({left:"0",opacity:"1"});
```

It does what I want, but there might be more properties affected in another functions and I don't want to change each element one by one. Is there a kind of UNDO for everything done by that jQuery sequence?

Comment: You can probably cache the computed styles of the element, and then selectively apply those that your jQuery functions have changed at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeattr/),  in this way, it will remove all inline styles added to class `.block2`

```
$(".block2").removeClass("Moved2").removeAttr("style")
```

Comment: I was not sure if that removes also styles defined in CSS file for that element. If it removes only inline styles added, then this is what I wanted

Comment: It removes only inline styles, because you are removing attribute html  `style`